# Cakephp SQL dump not showing queries

Tags: cakephp

For some reason my cakephp application is not showing any of the queries made to the database. It prints the table fine, but there are not records. What could cause this?

Comment: before you work? you can try to clear the cache.

Comment: I have the same problem, debug is set to 2, there are records being fetched on the index page but no query dump at the bottom. Still no solution. CakePHP version 2.4.0.

Comment: In my case, I just could not get it to print anything out. I ended up looking into `lib` and dumping the contents of the log. I think I wasn't getting it because of a dying query.

Answer (score 2):

Check to make sure you are pulling the records correctly.

```
$models = $this->Model->find('all');
// or
$this->Model->recursive = 0;
$this->set('models', $this->paginate());
```

Then when you add them in the view, be sure you are looping through them correctly:

```
foreach ($models as $model) {
    echo $model['Model']['field_name'];
}
```

**UPDATE**

To show the SQL statements, be sure you have the following set in core.php

```
Configure::write('debug', 2);
```

Also, in the Layout, besure you have this included someone between the `<body>` and `</body>` tags:

```
<?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?>
```

Comment: I am getting results perfectly fine. It's just not showing that cake made any queries.

Comment: I am confused as to what the problem is then. Are you looking for the actual queries?

Comment: See up update above. That will help you confirm that you have what is required to see the output of the SQL queries being made.

Comment: That's what I'm doing. But I get an empty table

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are getting an empty table with just the "Nr","Query","Error", etc. column headers?

You are getting the empty table because you have "Configure::write('debug',0);" set somewhere before you have "Configure::write('debug',2);" set. Find the first instance of it and delete it or change it to "2".

I know that you have long since fixed this problem but hopefully it helps somebody else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The [CakePHP debug kit](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit) can help you. After you install it, you will notice a small (pie-chart) icon on the top right of your CakePHP pages. Clicking on that will allow you to see various useful information, and most importantly for this issue, all the SQL queries that occurred in the back-end upon the page loading.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem in cakephp. I found that debug($variable) has limitation to the content size. Since you are fetching huge sized content from database, it is not able to print. Try doing print_r($variable) instead. To format it properly, you can do like this

```
echo "<pre>".print_r($variable)."</pre>";
```